# With Docker for Mac when using :cached bind mounts, are the delays on the host or the container?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-for-mac

[The osxfs caching page](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/osxfs-caching/), section `delegated` reads:

> For directories mounted with `delegated` the container’s view of the file system is authoritative, and writes performed by containers may not be immediately reflected on the host file system.

section `cached` reads:

> For directories mounted with `cached`, the host’s view of the file system is authoritative; writes performed by containers are immediately visible to the host, but there may be a delay before writes performed on the host are visible within containers.

This is unclear to me. If, using `cached`, the host's view of the system is authoritative, shouldn't that mean that if something changes on the host, it will be immediately reflected in the container? Why is the delay on the "authoritative" side?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In `:cached` mode reads of file attributes and file contents are cached by the containers with a long lifetime. When the content changes on the host a cache invalidation message is immediately sent to the containers to expire the cache entries -- this is quick but it isn't instantaneous. The documentation is talking about this delay.

Answer (score 0):

Authoritative data source always provides canonical, fresh data. Whenever there is a data corruption, we trust authoritative data source.

The DNS protocol is a good example:

1. Your computer caches a domain name resolution.
2. Intermediate name servers cache this domain name's DNS records retrieved from its authoritative name server.
3. Nameserver A keeps this domain name's canonical records.

That's why we call Nameserver A the authoritative name server of this domain. When records in Nameserver A are updated, the change might take hours to be visible to your computer.

Back to your question. The name, `cached`, already tells us what it provides. It gives us a relatively better read performance, but with the cost of data inconsistency.